# Does Rock band 3 and 4 work on PS4?

Tags: ps4, rock-band

I have a PS4 and would like to know whether I can run Rock Band 2 and 3 in my PS4 or not.

Answer (score 5):

Rock Band 2 and 3 are for PS3 only and Rock Band 4 is on PS4. You can however get the songs from earlier titles on Rock Band 4 using [song export packs](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP8802-CUSA02084_00-RBRB3DISCEXP2397), more info [here](https://www.polygon.com/2015/12/16/10299950/rock-band-4-3-song-export-import).